# finding smtp username and password for ubuntu postfix mail server?

Tags: email, codeigniter, ubuntu, smtp, postfix-mta

can someone tell me the command line call or file in an ubuntu postfix mail server to find my smtp username and password?

Or do you even need an smtp username and password for your server to send email?

if it is helpful i'm using PHP/Codeigniter which includes the email library described here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to send the email from php, you could just use default "Internet Site" postfix configuration and you wouldn't need to set up smtp authentication.

In production, you'd also need to add SPF record to your DNS zone to increase chances of avoiding spam filters.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe I should have posed this question more broadly, I'm unsure how much beyond typing what's described in this blog post I need to do: http://concisedeveloper.com/linux/how-to-install-smtp-server-on-ubuntu/ is there more to it than this? that seems too easy

Comment: It's really is pretty straightforward with postfix. A couple of things to watch out for: a) make sure postfix only accepts mail from local (loopback) interface b) For production use, setting SPI record for your domain is also very important step if you do any kind of mass mailing

Comment: i've never heard of the SPI record, would you mind pointing me to a link where I could investigate this? thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I meant SPF, not SPI record (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), it's usually best to use one of the record generating wizards, for instance http://www.mtgsy.net/dns/spfwizard.php (MSFT has one online as well).

Answer (score 0):

IF you have set up an ubuntu system then the default postfix install does not require a username or password.

Look for other problems that could prevent your sending email.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe I should have posed this question more broadly, I'm unsure how much beyond typing what's described in this blog post I need to do: http://concisedeveloper.com/linux/how-to-install-smtp-server-on-ubuntu/ is there more to it than this? that seems too easy